# How do I rotate an image manually without using cv2.getRotationMatrix2D

Tags: python, opencv

I want to rotate an image without using built-in cv2 library. So I have seen this equation

[image]

but I dont know how do I apply it in my code.

//edit

Comment: Why don’t you look at the source code of opencv? Or have you done that?

Answer (score 6):

This is generally done by iterating output image pixels and find which input image pixel it corresponds to, using rotation matrix for the inverse rotation. Some notes and improvements for below code:
1- Offsets are used because I am rotating image relative from center position (think of holding center of the image with a pen and rotating it around) instead of its topleft position.
2- I created image for maximum possible output size, a better way to do is calculate necessary output size from input image size and amount of rotation.
3- As commented in the code, instead of matching to a single pixel in input image, it is better to use linear interpolation with nearest 4 input image pixels when deciding the value of a pixel in the output image.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image


#  inputs
img = ndimage.imread("A.png")
rotation_amount_degree = 45

#  convert rotation amount to radian
rotation_amount_rad = rotation_amount_degree * np.pi / 180.0


#  get dimension info
height, width, num_channels = img.shape


#  create output image, for worst case size (45 degree)
max_len = int(math.sqrt(height*height + width*width))
rotated_image = np.zeros((max_len, max_len, num_channels))
#rotated_image = np.zeros((img.shape))


rotated_height, rotated_width, _ = rotated_image.shape
mid_row = int( (rotated_height+1)/2 )
mid_col = int( (rotated_width+1)/2 )

#  for each pixel in output image, find which pixel
#it corresponds to in the input image
for r in range(rotated_height):
    for c in range(rotated_width):
        #  apply rotation matrix, the other way
        y = (r-mid_col)*math.cos(rotation_amount_rad) + (c-mid_row)*math.sin(rotation_amount_rad)
        x = -(r-mid_col)*math.sin(rotation_amount_rad) + (c-mid_row)*math.cos(rotation_amount_rad)

        #  add offset
        y += mid_col
        x += mid_row

        #  get nearest index
        #a better way is linear interpolation
        x = round(x)
        y = round(y)

        #print(r, " ", c, " corresponds to-> " , y, " ", x)

        #  check if x/y corresponds to a valid pixel in input image
        if (x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < width and y < height):
            rotated_image[r][c][:] = img[y][x][:]


#  save output image
output_image = Image.fromarray(rotated_image.astype("uint8"))
output_image.save("rotated_image.png")
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If to add on top of "unlut", this is my answer to that:

```
def rotate_image(img, degrees, output_scale="crop"):

    # openCV solution:
    # x, y = image.shape
    # rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((x // 2, y // 2), angle, 1.0)
    # result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    assert output_scale in ["crop", "full"], "output_scale should be either 'crop' or 'full'"
    #  convert rotation amount to radian
    rot_rad = degrees * np.pi / 180.0
    rotate_m = np.array([[np.cos(rot_rad), np.sin(rot_rad)],
                         [- np.sin(rot_rad), np.cos(rot_rad)]])

    # If output_scale = "full", the image must be inserted into a bigger frame, so the coordinates would be translated
    # appropriately.
    gray_scale = False
    if len(img.shape) < 3:
        img = img.reshape(*img.shape, 1)
        gray_scale = True

    h, w, c = img.shape
    if output_scale == "full":
        diagonal = int(np.sqrt(h * h + w * w))   # Pytagoras theorm - the diagonal is the longest line in the rectangle
        im_padded = np.zeros((diagonal, diagonal, c))
        center_h = int((diagonal - h) // 2)
        center_w = int((diagonal - w) // 2)
        im_padded[center_h:-center_h, center_w:-center_w, :] = img
        img = im_padded
        rotated_image = np.zeros((diagonal, diagonal, c))
        h, w, c = img.shape
    else:
        rotated_image = np.zeros((h, w, c))

    # Rotate and shift the indices, from PICTURE to SOURCE (and NOT the intuitive way)
    indices_org = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(h), np.arange(w))).reshape(2, -1)
    indices_new = indices_org.copy()
    indices_new = np.dot(rotate_m, indices_new).astype(int)   # Apply the affineWrap
    mu1 = np.mean(indices_new, axis=1).astype(int).reshape((-1, 1))
    mu2 = np.mean(indices_org, axis=1).astype(int).reshape((-1, 1))
    indices_new += (mu2-mu1)   # Shift the image back to the center

    # Remove the pixels in the rotated image, that are now out of the bounds of the result image
    # (Note that the result image is a rectangle of shape (h,w,c) that the rotated image is inserted into, so in the
    # case of a "full" output_scale, these are just black pixels from the padded image...).
    t0, t1 = indices_new
    t0 = (0 <= t0) & (t0 < h)
    t1 = (0 <= t1) & (t1 < w)
    valid = t0 & t1
    indices_new = indices_new.T[valid].T
    indices_org = indices_org.T[valid].T

    #
    xind, yind = indices_new
    xi, yi = indices_org
    rotated_image[xi, yi, :] = img[xind, yind, :]

    if gray_scale:
        rotated_image = rotated_image.reshape((h, w))

    return rotated_image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Image library from PIL. This is another image manipulation library. Example shown below, and more infor can be found at:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("xyzabc.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
```

Comment: using library is way too easy, but I want to understanding to the core what's working inside that function how does it work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it makes sense to assume that the library takes a pixel value of (x, y) and switches the two values; after repeating this process for both pixels, the image would be rotated by 90 degrees. Rotating with any other angle involves some trigonometry.

Comment: “Using library is way too easy” - but you don’t know how to code this. So look at the source code for PIL or opencv.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what this equation tells you is, how to match coordinates from the initial image to the final image.
Note that the equation is for a rotation around 0.

The following is a C++ code but you can translate (interp2 is a fonction ton interpolate linearly between 4 neighboring pixels - and also return another value when outsite the original image):

```
for (int x=0; x<w_rotatedImg; x++)
  for (int y=0; y<h_rotatedImg; y++) {
    double previousImageX=(cos(theta)*(x-rotCenterX)-sin(theta)*(y-rotCenterY))+rotCenterX;
    double previousImageY=(sin(theta)*(x-rotCenterX)-cos(theta)*(y-rotCenterY))+rotCenterY;
    rotatedImage[y*w_rotatedImg+x] = interp2(initialImage, previousImageX, previousImageY);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Code shows how to Rotate the image 90 degree anticlockwise without using any predefined function or Module, 
cv2  is only used to read the image to be rotated   and then after applying the logic , to display the final rotated image 
Through this code You can rotate image of any size

```
img = cv2.imread(ImageName,1)
shape=img.shape
rev=[]
rev.append(shape[1])
rev.append(shape[0])
revF=tuple(rev)
rotate=np.zeros(revF,dtype=object)


for i in range (len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[i])):
             x=len(img[i])-1-j
             rotate[x][i]=img[i][j]

fi=[]
for i in range(len(rotate)):
    for j in range(len(rotate[i])):
       fi.append(rotate[i][j])
final=np.array(fi).reshape(revF[0],revF[1],3)
cv2.imshow("Image",final)
cv2.imwrite("ImageRotate90anti.jpg",(final))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a homogenous matrix of size 2x3. First 2x2 is the rotation matrix and last column is a translation vector.

[image]

Here's how to build your transformation matrix:

```py
# Exemple: Rotate img around center point
# angle = np.pi/6
# specific_point = np.array(img.shape[:2][::-1])/2

def rotate(img: np.ndarray, angle: float, specific_point: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    warp_mat = np.zeros((2,3))
    cos, sin = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
    warp_mat[:2,:2] = [[cos, -sin],[sin, cos]]
    warp_mat[:2,2] = specific_point - np.matmul(warp_mat[:2,:2], specific_point)
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, warp_mat, img.shape[:2][::-1])
```