# translate an image after rotation without using library

Tags: python, image-processing, rotation

I try to rotate an image clockwise 45 degree and translate the image -50,-50.
Rotation process works fine:(I refer to this page:[How do I rotate an image manually without using cv2.getRotationMatrix2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648391/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-manually-without-using-cv2-getrotationmatrix2d))

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image


#  inputs
img = ndimage.imread("A.png")
rotation_amount_degree = 45

#  convert rotation amount to radian
rotation_amount_rad = rotation_amount_degree * np.pi / 180.0


#  get dimension info
height, width, num_channels = img.shape


#  create output image, for worst case size (45 degree)
max_len = int(math.sqrt(height*height + width*width))
rotated_image = np.zeros((max_len, max_len, num_channels))
#rotated_image = np.zeros((img.shape))


rotated_height, rotated_width, _ = rotated_image.shape
mid_row = int( (rotated_height+1)/2 )
mid_col = int( (rotated_width+1)/2 )

#  for each pixel in output image, find which pixel
#it corresponds to in the input image
for r in range(rotated_height):
    for c in range(rotated_width):
        #  apply rotation matrix, the other way
        y = (r-mid_col)*math.cos(rotation_amount_rad) + (c-mid_row)*math.sin(rotation_amount_rad)
        x = -(r-mid_col)*math.sin(rotation_amount_rad) + (c-mid_row)*math.cos(rotation_amount_rad)

        #  add offset
        y += mid_col
        x += mid_row

        #  get nearest index
        #a better way is linear interpolation
        x = round(x)
        y = round(y)

        #print(r, " ", c, " corresponds to-> " , y, " ", x)

        #  check if x/y corresponds to a valid pixel in input image
        if (x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < width and y < height):
            rotated_image[r][c][:] = img[y][x][:]


#  save output image
output_image = Image.fromarray(rotated_image.astype("uint8"))
output_image.save("rotated_image.png")
```

However, when I try to translate the image. I edited the above code to this:

```
if (x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < width and y < height):
            rotated_image[r-50][c-50][:] = img[y][x][:]
```

But I got something like this:
[image: pic]

It seems the right and the bottom did not show the right pixel. How could I solve it?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The translation needs to be handled as a wholly separate step.  Trying to translate the value from the source image doesn't account for newly created 0,0,0 (if RGB) valued pixels by the rotation.

Further, simply subtracting 50 from the rotated array index values, without validating them at that stage for positivity, is allowing for a negative valued index, which is fully supported by Python.  That is why you are getting a "wrap" effect instead of a translation

You said your script rotated the image as intended, so while perhaps not the most efficient, the most intuitive is to simply shift the values of the image assembled *after* you rotate.  You could test that the values for the new image remain positive after subtracting 50 and only saving the ones >= 0 or being cognizant of the fact that you are shifting the values downward by 50, any number less than 50 will be discarded and you get:

```
<what you in the block you said was functional then:>

translated_image = np.zeros((max_len, max_len, num_channels))
for i in range(0, rotated_height-50): # range(start, stop[, step])
    for j in range(0, rotated_width-50): 
        translated_image[i+50][j+50][:] = rotated[i][j][:]

#  save output image
output_image = Image.fromarray(translated_image.astype("uint8"))
output_image.save("rotated_translated_image.png")
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this way. But the bottom and right will turn black. Actually there will be some  pixel there, how could I still maintain those pixels?

Comment: I edited the answer.  I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  That should take the rotated image and push it down 50 and to the right 50.